# react ListItem complains about id

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i'm new to react, and there is a warning in the console, when i display a list items, but i don't know why:

warning message: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Of course item.id is unique, because it comes from database (this is the id of the record), but the warning is still there.

**searchresult.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';

const SearchResult = ({ item }) => {
return (
<ListItem key={item.id}>
    <ListItemText primary={item.WordIT} secondary={item.WordHU} />
</ListItem>
)
}

export default SearchResult
```

**searchcard.js**

```
const translatedItems = translated.map(item =>
  <SearchResult item = {item} />
)

return (
<Card>
  <Grid item sx={ headerStyles.wrapper }>
    <SearchBar 
      placeholder="Search" 
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
  </Grid>
  <CardContent>
    <List>{translatedItems}</List>
  </CardContent>
</Card>
)
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `key` must be placed wherever you iterate a list. In this case, it must be placed on the `<SearchResult/>` element, not `<ListItem/>`